# esttab table from STATA with unaligned number of observations

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am trying to create a table using esttab option of STATA. I am able to edit the table out but the number of observations are not getting aligned. Moreover, is there a nice way to add table notes to regression tables?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{2004-05} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2011-12} \\
\midrule
Poverty Dummy & -4.170\sym{***} & -0.756 \\
& (1.254) & (1.314) \\
\addlinespace
Urban Dummy & 1.970 & 0.501 \\
& (1.630) & (1.370) \\
\midrule
R-squared & 0.425 & 0.392 \\
Observations & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2121} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3139} \\\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and containing the required packages (but not more!) that produces the output you are referring to. I guess, you use the `dcolumn` and the  `booktabs` packages?

Comment: If you want the numbers for the observations align with the other numbers in the same colum, don't put them in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` command which overrides the alignment and sets it to "centered".

Comment: As for the annotation line: I think it looks nice this way. I would probably remove the `@{}` to make the text align with the text in the other cells of the fist column.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes I am using the booktabs and dcolumn. If I remove ```\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}```  the observations row shifts towards the right

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it minimally compilable and of adding a screenshot. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you provide LaTeX a bit more information about the number of digits before and after the decimal marker in the two data columns. I.e., do replace `-1` in the third argument of the `D` column type with, say, `2.5` and `2.4`, respectively. This will enable LaTeX to do a much better job of placing the cell contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
% handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{2.5} d{2.4} @{}}
\toprule
& \mc{(1)}      & \mC{(2)}      \\
& \mc{2004--05} & \mC{2011--12} \\ % use en-dashes, not simple dashes
\midrule
Poverty dummy & -4.170\sym{***} & -0.756  \\
              & (1.254)         & (1.314) \\
\addlinespace
Urban dummy   &  1.970          &  0.501  \\
              & (1.630)         & (1.370) \\
\midrule
R$^{2}$       &  0.425          &  0.392  \\
No.\ of obs.  & \mc{2121}       & \mC{3139} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\footnotesize 
   \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I add `article` as document class and the two required packages to your code and if I remove the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` part from the relevant cells and just put the numbers directly, I get the following output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{2004-05} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2011-12} \\
\midrule
Poverty Dummy & -4.170\sym{***} & -0.756 \\
& (1.254) & (1.314) \\
\addlinespace
Urban Dummy & 1.970 & 0.501 \\
& (1.630) & (1.370) \\
\midrule
R-squared & 0.425 & 0.392 \\
Observations & 2121 & 3139 \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also removed the `@{}` from the annotation row to make it align with the text in the other cells in the first column.

If this is not what you want or if you get some other undesired output, you should extend your question by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the problem you encounter.